# Zathura background colour cannot be changed?

Tags: zathura

I saw yesterday that Zathura has changed in appearance.  It looks
better now, but the background colour is too bright for my liking
(I mean the colour at the edges, the background colour of the
document is still changed according to my zathurarc).  I don't remember how it used to
be, but I did't react to it before and now I do.  And I haven't
been able to find a variable that changes it.  Can it not be
changed?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Zathuras documentation](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/documentation/) you can use the [Girara settings](https://pwmt.org/projects/girara/options/) to style Zathura. From this we can derive that the `default-bg` variable can be used to specify the default background color.

As the customization of Zathura is managed via a config file at `~/.config/zathura/zathurarc`, you can simply add the line
`set default-bg "#000000"`

NOTE: You might have to create the `~/.config/zathura/zathurarc` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
:set recolor-darkcolor \#839496
```

in the normal mode, or put in the ~/.config/zathura/zathurarc